Applying 2-qubit noise to a multi qubit system using local operations in Python
I am trying to create a simulation of 2-qubit dephasing noise that acts on the first two qubits of a multi qubit system. I would like to do this locally rather than expanding my kraus operators into $2^n \times 2^n$ matrices and doing matrix multiplication.
I am using numpy, and einsum. At the moment, I generate my state into a $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix, and then reshape it to $(2,)*2n$. I've attempted to make the indices of the $(2,)*2n$ state such that the first $n$ are the bra's of the $n$ qubits and the second $n$ are the ket's of the $n$ qubits.
I then use einsum to apply $\rho\mapsto K \rho K^{\dagger}$
However applying even the identity element of the 4 kraus operators on the maximally mixed state it reorders the elements in the $2^n \times 2^n$ representation, and elements move to the off diagonals. Any help would be much appreciated as to how to properly apply this noise model.
def create_2qubit_kraus(D, p, noise_type):
        kraus_ops = [
            sqrt(1 - p) * np.kron(Basis.I(D, dtype=complex), Basis.I(D, dtype=complex)),
            sqrt((1 / 3) * p) * np.kron(Basis.Z(D, dtype=complex), Basis.I(D, dtype=complex)),
            sqrt((1 / 3) * p) * np.kron(Basis.I(D, dtype=complex), Basis.Z(D, dtype=complex)),
            sqrt((1 / 3) * p) * np.kron(Basis.Z(D, dtype=complex), Basis.Z(D, dtype=complex)),
        ]
        return kraus_ops


def transform_to_2s(matrix):
    N = int(np.log2(matrix.shape[0]))
    tensor_shape = (2,) * (2 * N)
    tensor = np.zeros(tensor_shape)

    for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        for j in range(matrix.shape[1]):
            binary_i = format(i, f'0{N}b')
            binary_j = format(j, f'0{N}b')

            position = tuple(int(bit) for bit in binary_i + binary_j)
            tensor[position] = matrix[i, j]

    return tensor


def transform_to_dimxdim(tensor):
    N = len(tensor.shape) // 2
    matrix_size = 2 ** N
    matrix = np.zeros((matrix_size, matrix_size))

    for position in np.ndindex(tensor.shape):
        binary_i = ''.join(str(bit) for bit in position[:N])
        binary_j = ''.join(str(bit) for bit in position[N:])

        i = int(binary_i, 2)
        j = int(binary_j, 2)

        matrix[i, j] = tensor[position]

    return matrix



def apply_kraus_pair(rho, kraus_ops, pair, N):
    dim = 2 ** N

    rho_tensor = transform_to_2s(rho)
    print(rho_tensor)
    new_rho_tensor = np.zeros_like(rho_tensor, dtype=complex)
    indices = generate_indices_string(pair, N)
    print(indices)
    # for k in kraus_ops:
    k_tensor = transform_to_2s(kraus_ops[0])
    print(k_tensor)
    contracted = np.einsum('abij, ijgkln, cdkl', k_tensor, rho_tensor, k_tensor.T.conj())

    new_rho_tensor += contracted

    # Reshape back to the original matrix form
    new_rho = transform_to_dimxdim(new_rho_tensor)

    return new_rho


D = 2  # Dimension for one qubit
N = 3 # Number of qubits
p = 0.1


rho = np.eye(D ** N, dtype=complex) / D ** N
print("Initial state:")
print(rho)


kraus_2q = create_2qubit_kraus(D, p, noise)
rho_new = apply_kraus_pair(rho, kraus_2q, pair, N)


print("Final state after applying 2-qubit noise:")
print(rho_new)



```

